# how to fix this mess under TFS?

Tags: tfs

so this is what I have

**valid changeset id 8

valid changeset id 7

valid changeset id 6

valid changeset id 5

invalid merge from branch X changeset id 4

valid changeset id 3

valid changeset id 2

valid changeset id 1**

is there a way to "delete" or "skip" or "ignore" the invalid changeset?

if not then I will lose a week to recover from this mess.

Comment: What do you mean by "invalid merge?"  Do you mean you've merged by mistake and need to take those changes out?

Comment: @Dan Pusey, something like this yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question "Is there a way to skip or otherwise ignore a changeset?"  The answer is no.

Which leaves you with three choices:

The first is to pull all the changes you want from 5 through 8 and rollback to 3.  Basically, get the files that changed and hand merge them into rev 3.

The second is to look at everything that the merge updated and hand rollback those items.  In short, depending on the number of files involved you are in for a long editing session.

The third option is only available to you if sets 5 through 8 did not modify the same files as 4.  If this is true then just select the files from the 4th set and roll those back individually.  Then check in the new set as #9.  Somehow I doubt this is available to you.

Comment: it seem i'm stuck with option #2 :-|

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFS 2010 then you can use the tf rollback command, this will attempt to remove the offending chagngeset. If there are conflicts because subsequentchangesets have modified the same code then the merge tool will appear and you can select the code you need to keep / remove.

For earlier versions of TFS you can install the TFS power tools and use the tfpt rollback command to do the same thing